# SignalR seems to not be using the root path that I give it when trying to connect

Tags: sockets, proxy, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have my SignalR server listening on the following URL:

```
http://staging.myserver.com/socket/signalr
```

I tested locally and it works, but when I deploy, I am running through an NGINX proxy (hence the `/socket/`)

When it tried to connect to the deployed SignalR server, it is failing and I can see that it is attempting to connect using a URL with the `/socket/` ommitted.

I have tried to debug to see if there is a sport where it strips everything but the base url  and appends `/signalr` but I can't seem to find anything.

I am able to hit the following URL and see my hubs perfectly fine.

```
http://staging.myserver.com/socket/signalr/hubs
```

I just don't know why it is omitting the `/socket` from the url when trying to connect.

Here is more or less an example of what I have

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://staging.myserver.com/socket/signalr');
        var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
    contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(name, message) {
        console.log(name + ' ' + message);
    });
    connection.start().done(function() {
            //blah blah
        });
```

I can see it taking the correct URL when it first initializes the connection, but somewhere along the way, it defaults back to

```
http://staging.myserver.com/signalr
```

The only way I have been able to get around it is by adding an addition proxy to `/` on my NGINX proxy. This is not something that will be able to stick so I need to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please see GitHub issues [#3649](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3649) and [#3287](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3287) which describe the same issue and give some pointers specific to IIS on how to transform the content within the response to the connection negotiation to re-write the URL property. It appears that the URL within the response from the server is used to set a local variable called `appRelativeUrl` on the client side which is used for subsequent interaction. So another less palatable workaround is to modify/configure the SignalR server using `app.MapSignalR("/socket/signalr", hubConfiguration);` but I haven't gone that route to see whether it would cause other problems.